# Servers lose network connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

Machines lose network connection from time to time.

They're still working, I have a speedtest running on a RPi4 and from the screenshot bellow we can see that there are no stats for a while in the top graph, and on the requests (bottom right) we see the failed attempts.

[image]

Hopefully this can help in any way to give some ideas of the possible issue:

- the wifi routers and wifi points are from [Google Nest](https://store.google.com/us/product/nest_wifi?hl=en-US)
- on the wifi router I have the RPi with PiHole as the main DNS and `1.1.1.1` as secondary
- the RPi also works as the main point of access for all the web services

The home set up looks like bellow:

[image]

I don't even know how to start debugging.

Any ideas of what should I do to test/debug this?

Comment: Do they also lose connection to _other_ things besides that one Speedtest server somewhere far away? Do they lose connection to hosts within the same LAN, both on the same Nest node and between different ones? Do they all lose connection at the same time, or is it just the "main" Speedtest Pi that's showing problems? Try to `ping` the problematic Pi from another, or from your laptop, or from your other laptop.

Comment: Actually, does this Pi always stay associated to the same Nest node (the "Wifi router") the whole time, or does it sometimes decide to roam to another, or lose the Wi-Fi connection entirely? Check its `dmesg` or run `iw event -r` to keep track of Wi-Fi events.

Comment: I think once of the times I couldn't access the NAS directly (not even ping reached) but was able to ssh to the server in the attic (the one connected through the switch), and if I recall correctly I was able to access the NAS from that machine .

Comment: Since this only happens from time to time, it would be ideal to get some commands I could try next time to help debug. I've let `iw event -r > /home/ml/network-events.txt` running, I'll check the output next time it fails. And I'm not sure what I should be looking in the [`dmesg` output](https://pastebin.com/yPqzX9d5)